# Why is my matrix showing the wrong output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to find the permutations of the array [1,2,3] using recursion. Everything is working fine if I directly print out the permutations in the base case but I want to store all the permutations in a separate array. I am doing that by pushing the arrays into the matrix but it shows the wrong output that is all the arrays being pushed are the same. I can't find out what the bug is. Please help.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let matrix = [];
let index = 0;

function perm(arr, index) {
    if (index === arr.length) {
        console.log('arr:', arr);
        matrix.push(arr);
        return;
    }

    for (let i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
        [arr[i], arr[index]] = [arr[index], arr[i]];
        perm(arr, index + 1);
        [arr[i], arr[index]] = [arr[index], arr[i]];
    }
}

perm(arr, index);
console.log(matrix);
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
arr: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
arr: [ 1, 3, 2 ]
arr: [ 2, 1, 3 ]
arr: [ 2, 3, 1 ]
arr: [ 3, 2, 1 ]
arr: [ 3, 1, 2 ]
[
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are pushing the same array `arr` multiple time into `matrix`, so when you update it later, it update all the lines in `matrix` since they are the same reference to the same array.

Try duplicating the array `arr` before:

```
matrix.push(arr.slice());
```

Comment: I am new to coding and still learning. Can you please show me what changes I should make to the code?

Comment: use slice() to make a copy of the array when you push it into matrix, as shown in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly.